# High CPU usage for Apache server on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

Wondering if anyone know's why the processes below are taking up some much CPU resources on my Ubuntu apache server.

- 100% `/usr/sbin/acpi`
- 71% `/usr/local/apa`
- 68% `/sbin/syslogd`
- 66% `/usr/sbin/cron`
- 59% `/sbin/klogd`

If I run strace on most of the processes I see

```
select(8, [3], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Once I stop the process the CPU usage goes back to normal but after an hour our so everything starts maxing out again.

I haven't setup anything in the cron for this server. So not sure exactly what the cron is doing.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: With such a usage of rsyslogd and klogd I guess your system is logging LOTs of things. Please can you check your log files and report us accordingly? Also, what's exactly /usr/local/apa?

Comment: Great question lol.. I'll checkout both and get back to you.

Comment: While trying to figure out what

select(8, [3], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)

I ran lsof -p {acpi process id} -ad 3

and got

/usr/sbin 21798 www-data 3u IPv4 10901916 0t0 TCP ip-10-169-241-28.ec2.internal:46985->li498-11.members.linode.com:ircd (CLOSE_WAIT)

So it looks like it getting caught up on this? Not sure why my server is calling linode.com.. I'm starting to think I've been hacked or something.

Comment: +1: if /usr/bin/acpi is making IRC connection and use 100% of CPU time, you can bet you've "guests" inside your system. Anyway, still wondering what it's logging. Ad for "apa", do you know what's doing?

Comment: Here is what I got running Ad on apa /usr/loca 17661 www-data    3u  IPv4 10903990      0t0  TCP ip-10-169-241-28.ec2.internal:42538->ns313760.ovh.net:ircd (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: "irc", again. That's surely the time to check this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Yup sounds like you've been hacked and may be running some botnet clients controlled through irc channels. Since they run as www-data sounds like some web site you have got compromised (any wordpress there?). Btw, those command lines are probably fake, those botnet clients just rewrote $ARGV[0] to confuse you.

Comment: Yeah...... It's not good.. I've discovered it's pretty much a total compromise.. Thanks for your help guys. I've got some work to do.

Comment: It was a Magento shop btw.